# Call Web control's JavaScript Function From Button Click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've got a Web control called Fou.ascx and it has a java script function called DoFou(message).
In my web Page I want to click a button, which is on the page and not part of the web control, and have it execute DoFou and pass in the message parameter.
The web page has an instance of the web control Fou.

How can I do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the button is a server control, in the code behind you can do something like

```
myButton.Attributes.Add("onClick", "doFou('" + myMessage + "');");
```

If the button is not a server control and assuming that myMessage is accessible in the ascx you can do something like

```
<input type="button" onclick='<%= "doFou(\"" + myMessage + "\");" %>' value="myButton" />
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work, when I view the page's source I don't see DoFou and all DoFou has is alert(messsage); and nothing pops up.

Comment: i did attribute.add suggestion, i see it in the button's onclick

Comment: ahh, my control was invisible, when I changed it to visible it works]